# Given 2 vectors $u, v$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and a Gaussian random vector with ${\cal N}(0, I)$

Tags: vector-spaces, normal-distribution, gaussian

What is the probability that the signs of $u \cdot g$ and $v \cdot g$ are the same?

My attempt:

Denote $\theta(x, y)$ as an angle between $a, b \in \mathbb R^n$ (between $0$ and $pi$).

Then, $$P(sign(u \cdot g) = sign(v \cdot g)) 
\\= P(sign(\cos(\theta(u, g))) = sign(\cos(\theta(v, g)))) 
\\= P(\theta(u, g) \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}], \theta(v, g) \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]) + P(\theta(u, g) \in (\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi], \theta(v, g) \in (\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi])$$

$|\theta(u, g)  - \theta(v, g)| \leq \theta(u, v) \leq \theta(u, g) + \theta(v, g)$, so
$$P(\theta(u, g) \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}], \theta(v, g) \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]) = E[1_{[\theta(u, g) \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}], \theta(v, g) \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]]}] 
\\= E[E[1_{[\theta(u, g) \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}], \theta(v, g) \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]]} | \theta(u, g)]]$$

but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What is g, I don't understand

Comment: g is a random vector in $\mathbb R^d$ whose each coordinnate is distributed as ${\cal N} (0, 1)$.